Name of the command "search" on Matlab on Linux + How to change it
I have to use Matlab for work (Matlab 2019b on Ubuntu 22.04). Under Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts, there is a list of command accessible via keyboard shortcut which the user can customize. I cannot find the command "search" (which would be a simple Ctrl + f on most other programs and operating system: What is the name of the command and how can I change it?

What do you mean by "search": search for text in the editor, or something else? Search for text is called "find" in that menu, and it has the default shortcut ctrl-F

@LuisMendo thank you for your comment. Yes exactly. Search for text. So maybe I did not write  (capital) but  instead. I will try that. However I do not find the "search" command in the shortcut list (also some other basic ones such as "copy" or "paste" are there)

It’s called “find”, not “search”

many thanks for your answer @LuisMendo. Feel free to post an answer that I will be glad to accept

Done! Hand-drawn red line and all, in the best tradition of the site :-)

In Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts, the name of the command that searches for text is Find..., and its default keyboard shortcuts are Ctrl+F and Ctrl+H, as shown in the following image (Matlab R2019a, names of keys are in Spanish):

